# Creaing user input to manipulate data with a set of criterias

Tags: vba, excel

I am having problems with a VBA Excel 2010 program code.

I am trying to read data from a spreadsheet on excel 2010. what I have is a set of data (see below) and I am trying to write a code that will let me use a msg box and ask me to write down the name I am looking for e.g. "Name 1" from the list of names in the column and then I want to set a criteria where if the number in the columns are equal to zero and again for a different column = 0 ("name 5"), then highlight red any number in column "Name 8 and Name 9" that is greater than let say 30 (just a random example). the important thing is, the red highlight of column "Name 8/9" must only occur if the numbers is row "Name 1" and "Name 5" are equal to zero.

I have already done this but I only used the column numbers e.g. A1:A5. now I need to use the name of the column because I want to use the code for a different excel spreadsheets but the names of columns are in different positions for each excel sheet, but if I use the names, no matter which column along excel they are I will always find the right column I am looking for and set the criteria.

the criteria for "Name 1/5" will always be = 0 or =1 but the program has to ask me to choose that when I search for it.

if you look below at the example, you can see the red highlight are when criteria of =0 is met for Name 1 and Name 5 and the number in Name8/9 are greater than 30. when it is not greater than 30 and it still meets the criteria it is highlighted blue in the excel spreadsheet example. ALL OTHER NAMES MUST BE IGNORED.

SEE EXAMPLE BELOW

```
Name 1  Name 2  Name 3  Name 4  Name 5  Name 6  Name 7  Name 8  Name 9  Name 10
0       0       1       0       0       1       58      35      14      19
0       0       0       0       0       1       41      45      68      74
1       0       1       0       1       0       23      18      98      87
0       0       1       0       0       1       65      36      52      89
0       0       0       0       1       1       24      95      47      75
1       1       1       0       1       0       58      87      59      14
0       1       0       0       0       0       74      41      84      32
1       1       0       0       1       0       96      25      74      96
0       0       0       0       0       0       87      35      15      53
0       0       1       0       0       1       57      49      48      47
1       0       1       0       1       1       63      84      23      65
0       1       0       0       0       0       21      54      69      12
0       0       1       0       0       0       54      23      54      54
1       1       0       0       1       1       88      34      77      88
0       0       1       0       0       0       78      48      68      69
1       0       1       0       0       1       96      87      14      65
1       0       0       0       1       0       21      96      54      25
0       1       0       0       0       0       54      72      78      29
0       1       1       0       0       1       62      38      22      78
0       0       0       0       0       0       21      49      65      54
1       0       1       0       1       1       17      65      98      99
0       0       0       0       0       0       59      15      56      70
0       1       1       0       0       0       36      12      29      54
1       0       0       0       1       0       29      49      55      54
```

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click() 
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 
    For Each rw In Range("A1:V22").Rows 
        If Application.Sum(rw.Resize(, 4)) = 0 Then 
            cll.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 
            For Each cll In rw.Offset(, 4).Resize(, 18).Cells 
                If cll.Value > 50 Then cll.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 
            Next cll 
        End If 
    Next rw 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is what i have so far also the numbers and the cells are a bit different. this code used cell locations rather than column name.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading right what you want, you could try this. This will ask you to input the name and will then go through your motions on that particular column as a range for the loops. Is that what you are after?

Also, I've changed

```
If Application.Sum(rw.Resize(, 4)) = 0 Then 
        cll.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

To rw.Interior.Colorindex = 3 - as I'm guessing this was an error (as you can't use a variable outside of its loop

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

searchstring = InputBox("Input name?")

Set coll = Rows(1).Find(What:=searchstring, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If coll Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Name not found"
    Exit Sub
Else
    coll = coll.Column
    Lrow = Range(Cells(2, coll), Cells(2, coll)).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
End If

    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    For Each rw In Range(Cells(2, coll), Cells(Lrow, coll))

        If Application.Sum(rw.Resize(, 4)) = 0 Then
            rw.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            For Each cll In rw.offset(, 4).Resize(, 18).Cells
                If cll.Value > 50 Then cll.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Next cll
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great but I want to be able to search for three three diffeent name and set the criteria( a message box that asks me whether I want it to be 1 or 0 ). so search name 1  ask me for criteria , 1 or 0 then name 2 then name 3.

Comment: Bearing that in mind, why not have a look at creating a custom form?
You could have 3 text boxes and 3 toggle boxes to choose your criteria. Its not great coding practice to have lots of things popping up one after another - when one thing would do

Comment: Any idea how I could do that, sorry very new to this. Thanks

Comment: To start with, press Alt + F11 to get you to the VBA editor - then right click on your project and add a userform. There's loads of tutorials online to get you on the right track.